# Sitecore 8.0 Palette.aspx error

Tags: sitecore

Is there somebody knows what this error occurs?

In placeholder, we can add more than one rendering item. If I click the placeholder, there are two "Add here" button on top and at the bottom in the placeholder.

If I use the button on the top, I can add another rendering item. But, if I use the button at the bottom, I get a error.

I have checked Broswer WebTool and it says

`POST http://mysitename.com/sitecore/shell/Applications/WebEdit/Palette.aspx 500 (Internal Server Error)`

and checked log file

```
Nested Exception

Exception: System.FormatException
Message: Unrecognized Guid format.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result)
   at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
   at Sitecore.Data.ShortID.Parse(String value)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.ExecuteInsertRenderingArgs.b__0(String id)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.InsertRendering.InsertRenderingAt(DeviceDefinition device, RenderingDefinition renderingDefinition, Int32 insertPosition, IEnumerable`1 allowedRenderingsIds)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.InsertRendering.Process(PipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.ExecutePageEditorAction.ExecutePageEditorActionPipeline.Run(ExecutePageEditorActionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Palette.OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I guess this is similar with [Experience Editor issue while adding any component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388824/experience-editor-issue-while-adding-any-component).

Comment: This a plain-jane install, or are you running any kind of customizations?

Comment: We don't have any special installation and it happens after upgrading to SC 8.0.